# performSegue causes Warning Attempt to present while a presentation is in progress

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

Hello I have a button that must present a modal view controller when tapped
Here is the action:

```
- (IBAction)addNewLevelAction:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kNewLevelConfigureSegue sender:self];
}
```

in prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:kNewLevelConfigureSegue]) {
        PSLevelConfigViewController *dest = (PSLevelConfigViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        dest.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

However when I tapp it I get:

```
 Warning: Attempt to present <PSLevelConfigViewController: 0x98cbd00> on <UINavigationController: 0x98aac70> while a presentation is in progress!
```

Why is this? There is no other presentation there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you perform the segue programmatically, the segue must be connected to the controller and not directly to the button. 
Check if your storyboard is set correctly (post some screenshots if you need help). 
In such situation, if your segue is connected to the button AND, at the same time, to an action that performs it programmatically,  your segue will be performed twice, and the second perform will cause that error.